# how to style only a part of text in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-select

I need to add superscript in dropdownlist options. I tried many ways but nothing worked out.
So help me to how to style a only a part of option text to make it appear like superscript.
please help me,also if you know any other way to add superscript in dropdownlist options. thanks

Comment: Why the italics, it does not help you get answers.

Comment: I tried that option also, but the size of that superscript is not looking good in IE. I forced to try other options..

Comment: yes in firefox its looking good. But in IE the size is so small..:-(:-(

Answer (score 2):

***There is no way to do this in HTML/CSS/Javascript***

However for all those trying to do it out of a `<select>` tag, wrap the content you intend to superscript in a `<span>` element and then apply CSS to it.

**Example**

*HTML*

```
<p>x<span class="superscript">2</span> = 9</p>
```

*CSS*

```
span.superscript { vertical-align: super; font-size:50%; }
```

***[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gBkjv/)***

Comment: Agreed, this is what I would do.

Comment: but we can't add <span> in options tag, right..Is there any other way..

Comment: @user2907330 I didn't know that, I'm looking for a solution now!

Comment: thank u jumpingcode..

Comment: from morning i am trying..but cant find perfect solution..Please help me to solve this issue..

Comment: I guess you want something along these lines: http://jsfiddle.net/NuqU8/

Comment: it seems good..thank u jumpingcode

Comment: How can we toggle on/off this superscript.Saw we create a span for adding that superscript.Now I want to disable it,how can i do that?